# Creating multi-value choice list of field values and using selected for select in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, tool-validation, choice-list

I am using ArcMap 10.3.

I have created a multi-value choice list following this blogpost:

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/16/generating-a-multivalue-choice-list/

I changed the validation code to my needs but now I am stuck.
Basically I want the script to use the selected values of the choice list and 1) change them all to a another field value (optional)
2) apply a select analysis on it.

My validation code so far looks like this:

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
"""Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

def __init__(self):
"""Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

def initializeParameters(self):
"""Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
called when the tool is opened."""
    return

def updateParameters(self):
"""Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
has been changed."""
    if self.params[0].value and self.params[1].value:
        self.params[2].filter.list = sorted({row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(self.params[0].value, self.params[1].value.value) if row[0]})

def updateMessages(self):
"""Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return
```

My user interface looks like this:
[image]

How can I do this?

Update:
The part of the script, where I don't know what to do:

```
inputFC= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #input Feature Class, type: feature layer
inputField =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #input Field, type: Field
Values = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # field values, type: String
OutputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #output, type: feature layer

where = "\"inputField"\" = Values
arcpy.Select_analysis(inputFC, OutputFC, where)
```

The problem lies in the parameters of the select_analysis part. I don't know how to access the values the user selected to use them in an SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import arcpy

inputFC= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #input Feature Class, type: feature layer
inputField =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #input Field, type: Field
Values = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # field values, type: String
OutputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #output, type: feature layer

valueList = [x.strip() for x in Values.split(";")]

dateVal = 0

fieldInfo = arcpy.ListFields(inputFC, inputField)[0]
fieldType = fieldInfo.type
if fieldType == 'String':
    where = "{} IN ('{}')".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(inputFC, inputField), "', '".join(valueList))
elif fieldType == 'Date':
    arcpy.AddError("Doesn't work nice with dates!")
    dateVal = 1
else:
    where = "{} IN ({})".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(inputFC, inputField), ", ".join(valueList))

if not dateVal:
    arcpy.Select_analysis(inputFC, OutputFC, where)
```

You have to convert your multi-value string of field values into a list of values and then concatenate them into your `where` clause.  The `where` clause is constructed slightly differently for `String` fields from other types.

This doesn't work nicely with dates at this stage - I'm still looking into how to deal to the dates here and will post an edit if I find a solution.